# Javascript: input value interpreted as undefined parameter in callback function

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, jquery-callback

I am having an issue with passing a String value to a callback function from a jQuery plugin:

here is the code from the plugin

```
tempField.on("keydown", function (e){
    if (e.which === 13) {
    var hiddenField = $('input[name="hiddenField"]');
        var textValue = $(this).val();
        var textColor = settings.color;
        var font = settings.textSize;
        var removeInputHandle = $(this).remove();
        var setText = textElement.show();
    }

    if(textValue != ""){
        hiddenField.val(textValue).change();
        textElement.text(textValue);
        textElement.css("color", textColor);
        textElement.css("font-size", font);
        settings.callback(textValue);
    }

    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        removeInputHandle;
        setText;
    }

    return textValue;
});
```

and code from the main js file

```
var setTitle = function (title){
    title = presTitle;
    var presTitle = app.presentation.title;
    console.log(presTitle);
};

$("#presentationTitle").inline({
    callback: setTitle
});
```

now, the callback function here is replacing the callbackfunction defined in the plugin file through the $.extend function (just so that no one is confused).

I am trying to use textValue to set the value of a field in an object. But this value needs to be a string... and the value is not being passed as a string and is interpreted as undefined or null; eventhough it gives the the alfa numeric value.

EX:

say, I entered into the input field, someinputinthisinputfield. The value will be someinputinthisinputfield.

I need it to be "someinputinthisinputfield".

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `var textValue` before the first `if` statement. Currently, you're returning nothing because `textValue` doesn't exist in the scope that the `return` would return it in. You need something like

```
tempField.on("keydown", function(e) {
    var textValue;
    ...
});
```

You could initialize `textValue` to `""`, and it would work in your second `if` check as well.

Comment: it still does not seem to work. Maybe I should be using better logic here

Comment: @dumble Is your callback ever being fired? Also, you are calling a parameter in the `setTitle` function, but are never passing one in.